# get max value of each column group by student ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns like this

```
Std_id  Class Section
14        8      2
14        8      1
14        9      1
15        8      3
15        8      2
15        8      1

Now I want student max class and max section by unique Student ID Like this

Std_id  Class Section
14        9      1
15        8      3
```

I tried following queries with no success

```
SELECT std_id, class, section FROM `session` GROUP BY std_id ORDER BY std_id ASC,class DESC,section DESC
```

And

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id, class_id, section_id FROM `student_session` ORDER BY student_id ASC,class_id DESC,section_id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this query

```
SELECT std_id, MAX(class),MAX(section) FROM student GROUP BY std_id
```

Comment: Sorry it is not working, showing max value of each columns, but I want max class and max section of max class

Comment: Correction 
This must work, Try it

SELECT std_id, MAX(class) as class,MAX(section) as section FROM student WHERE class = (SELECT MAX(class) FROM student)  GROUP BY std_id,class

Answer (score 1):

It should help:

```
SELECT Std_id, MAX(Class) as max_class, MAX(Section) as max_section 
FROM student 
GROUP BY Std_id
```

Comment: Thank you for this correction. There is should be `Std_id`